# How to reverse unlimited sub categories in Laravel using recursive relations

Tags: php, laravel

I developped an unlimited sub categories system using recursive relations to get as many sub categories levels as it could find. For example, if I'm in one page with Category 1, I will see the sub categories Category 11 and Category 12. And if I go to to the page with Category 11, I will see the others sub categories depending on this last Category 11, for example Category 111, Category 112 and Category 113. Etc.

This image is what I get with the following code :
[image]

For this, I created 2 relations in my Categories model :

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Categories::class);
}

public function childrenCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Categories::class)->with('categories');
}
```

After in my Categories Controller I made a request to my database with relations :

```
$categoriesTree = Categories::whereNull('categories_id')
     ->with('childrenCategories')
     ->get();

(...)

return view('categories.index', compact('categoriesTree'));
```

And in my blade view, I did :

```
<select class="form-control select2">
       <option value="0">Choose a category</option>
       @php $nb = 0; @endphp
       @foreach($categoriesTree as $category)
           <option value="{{ $category->id }}" data-name="{{ $category->name_fr }}">{{ $category->name_fr }}</option>
           @foreach ($category->childrenCategories as $childCategory)
               @include('categories.child_categories', ['child_categories' => $childCategory, 'nb' => $nb])
           @endforeach
       @endforeach
</select>
```

And the child_categories file included is :

```
@php $nb++; @endphp
<option value="{{ $child_categories->id }}" data-name="{{ $child_categories->name_fr }}">{{ ' ' . str_repeat('---', $nb) . ' ' . $child_categories->name_fr }}</option>
@foreach ($child_categories->childrenCategories as $childCategory)
    @include('categories.child_categories', ['child_categories' => $childCategory])
@endforeach
```

***My question is*** :
How can I get a reverse unlimited sub categories to have breadcrumb like this image ? For example, if I'm in category 111, I would like to see this :
[image]

I have no idea how to do this. Thanks!!

Comment: you may want to look into the alternatives to adjacency lists so you don't actually have to do things recursively ... something like closure table or nested sets perhaps, especially if you don't know the depths  ... this might be nice to take a look at https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do a recursive method, thanks because of your advices about the belongsTo() method, I could do a recursive blade :

```
// Categories model
public function parentsCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, 'categories_id')->with('parentsCategories');
}

// Categories Controller
$categoriesBreadcrumb = Categories::where('id', $category_id)
    ->with('parentsCategories')
    ->first();

//index.blade.php
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        @if(is_object($categoriesBreadcrumb))
            @include('categories.parents_categories', ['categoriesBreadcrumb' => $categoriesBreadcrumb->parentsCategories])
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                {{ $categoriesBreadcrumb->name_fr }}
            </li>
        @endif
    </ol>
</nav>

// parents_categories.blade.php (recursive)
@if(is_object($categoriesBreadcrumb))
     @include('categories.parents_categories', ['categoriesBreadcrumb' => $categoriesBreadcrumb->parentsCategories])
     <li class="breadcrumb-item">
         <a href="{{ route('collections.index', ['category_id' => $categoriesBreadcrumb->id ]) }}">{{ $categoriesBreadcrumb->name_fr }}</a>
     </li>
@endif
```

So the final breadcrumb result is : if I'm in Category 1111, I can see :

Category 1 / Category 11 / Category 111 / Category 1111

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You Can Try This Way:

```
// Category.php
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

// To access CategoryController.php
$category->children; // sub-categories collection

$category->parent; // parent instance
```

Comment: With this method we can't get parents tree. Only get one parent. And don't forget about laravel's n+1 query

Answer (score 1):

You can get its parents like this

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class)->with('parent');
}
```

```
Category::with('parent')->first();
```